# Python - Evaluating logic stored in a database in the string

Tags: python, database, eval

What is the best approach to evaluate logic stored in a string in Python?

If I have a string like:

```
if [value1] > 3 and [value2] < 4 then <myfunc()> else <print("else")>
```

stored in a database (it's a django app that allows users to set their own rules). Note that the variables inside [] can be chosen by the user. Note also that the functions inside <> can also be chosen by the user.

It should convert to:

```py
if value1 > 3 and value2 < 4:
    myfunc()
else:
    print("else")
```

I am not sure where to start in converting this string into logic.

Comment: The String in the database and the Python code are equivalent. What is your question?

Comment: My question is once I have read the string from the database, how can I execute it like a logical statement?